# Trick elapsed visitation time when visiting a website using Python & selenium

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Ok, so I am trying to create a program that allows the background of my Gnome desktop to tap into the stream of wallpapers used by Google's chromecast devices.

Currently I use a loop function in Python that uses selenium and a Chrome webdriver to get the images that are dynamically displayed here:

https://clients3.google.com/cast/chromecast/home/

My function works exactly like I want it to. **However the problem is** > whenever I visit this website in a browser it starts displaying random wallpapers in a random order, there seems to be a big selection of possible wallpapers, but whenever you reload the page it always shows only about 5 (max) different wallpapers.. since my script reloads the page in each loop, I only get about 5 different wallpapers out of it, while there should be a multitude of that available via the website.

**That leads me to question**: Can I use selenium for Python to somehow trick the website into thinking I've been around longer then just a few seconds and thereby maybe showing me a different wallpaper?

**NB**: I know I could also get the wallpapers from non-dynamic websites such as [this one](https://chromecastbg.alexmeub.com/), I already got that one to work, but the goal now is to actually tap into the live Chromecast stream. I've searched if there might be an API somewhere for it, but couldn't find one so decided to go with my current approach.

My current code:

```
import io
import os
from PIL import Image
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from random import shuffle
import requests
import sched
from selenium import webdriver
import subprocess
import time

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def change_desktop():
    display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
    display.start()

    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    urllist = ["https://clients3.google.com/cast/chromecast/home/v/c9541b08", "https://clients3.google.com/cast/chromecast/home"]
    shuffle(urllist)
    browser.get(urllist[0])
    element = browser.find_element_by_id("picture-background")
    image_source = element.get_attribute("src")
    browser.quit()
    display.stop()

    request = requests.get(image_source)
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(request.content))
    image_format = image.format
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    temp_local_image_location = current_dir + "/interactive_wallpaper." + image_format
    image.save(temp_local_image_location)
    subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/gsettings", "set", "org.gnome.desktop.background", "picture-uri", "'" + temp_local_image_location + "'"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    s.enter(30, 1, change_desktop())

s.enter(30, 1, change_desktop())
s.run()
```